# Redirection with iron-router and onBeforeAction on meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor app and with the package `iron-router`, I try to block all pages if the user is not connected except fews pages. And if nothing is specified we go on the landing page.
So in the file router.js, I have :

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) { 
        Router.go('login');
    } else {
    this.next();
    }
}, {
except: [
    "login", "landing", "register", "forgotPassword" 
]
});

Router.route('/', function () {
    Router.go('landing');
});
```

But when I go on `localhost:3000/` I'm redirected to login page and not to the landing page.

If I remove the onBeforeAction function, I'm redirect to the landing page.
So it must be a problem with this 2 functions but I don't know where. Maybe I need to precise the "/" in the exceptions but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the route `'/'` in your exceptions too, otherwise this is caught by the `onBeforeAction`

Try re-defining as follows

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) { 
        Router.go('login');
    } else {
    this.next();
    }
}, {
except: [
    "default", "login", "landing", "register", "forgotPassword" 
]
});

Router.route('/', function () {
    Router.go('landing');
}, { 
    name: "default"
} );
```

In this case you name the route and then you can add it to your exception list

see http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#named-routes